# "Unknown selected data source for Port iPhone" after phone call

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I have a video chat app, On my iPhone 5s, when in video chat, once GSM phone call come in, the Xcode always print out a log:

> 2013-12-17 14:50:00.826 xxxxx[2485:780f] 14:50:00.826 ERROR:
>   [0xad85000] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:50: ValidateRequiredFields:
>   Unknown selected data source for Port iPhone È∫¶ÂÖãÈ£é (type:
>   MicrophoneBuiltIn)

which only happen on iPhone5' device, and my iPhone4s has no such problem, does someone know what this log meaning, and how to fix it.

Comment: Does it do anything else besides that? Ie, is anything breaking? If not, I would probably just ignore it and just file a bug report about it. Internal Apple frameworks sometimes love to barf the console full of stuff that isn't really relevant to you.

Comment: It seems nothing breaking, your suggestion is a good idea, i will file a bug to Apple. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having similar problem. It happens only at the initial stage..

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you deactivate the session
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
session.setActive(false, error: nil)
And when you do now activate it again.

Comment: It happens even in case of setActive true